# How do define the return type of var as empty array in the struct?

Tags: swift, struct, swift5

During API call I'm getting the var hobbies as `[]`
so how can I define the var having type empty array

```
{
  "name": "Alex",
  "hobbies": []
}
```

```
struct User : Decodable{
var name : String
var hobbies : []
}
```

Comment: Your hobbies key is not going to be empty always, right? What type of data you are going to have in hobbies?

Comment: Hobbies should be the type it has when it's not empty. For e.g. [Hobby] can have a value of [] (an empty array).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the hobbies array of Int:

```
struct User{
    var name : String
    var hobbies:[Int]
}
```

Usage:

```
let user = User(name: "Test", hobbies: [0,1,2])
```

Comment: But what if the ```hobbies[]``` does not contain any data then what should I do??

Comment: @USB you can put Any instead of Int

Comment: when I tried var hobbies: [Any]  I'm getting "Cannot automatically synthesize 'Decodable' because '[Any]' does not conform to 'Decodable'" error

Answer (score 0):

Even though the array responded from your API is empty, but it must have its own type.

I believe you can't declare as `No Type Array`. At least, you can declare it as

`var hobbies: [Any]` if you don't know the type of that respond

Comment: when I tried ```var hobbies: [Any]```  I'm getting  "Cannot automatically synthesize 'Decodable' because '[Any]' does not conform to 'Decodable'"  error

Comment: If you're using `Decodable`, make sure you know the correct type of your response.
Try to talk to your Back-end Dev to know what's the type of `hobbies`.

Example if your back-end dev said `hobbies`'s type of [String] so just put

`var hobbies: [String]`

Answer (score 0):

Tried this?

```
struct User {
 var name : String
 var hobbies:[String]?
}
```